# Connecting to specific path in s3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm trying to connect to specific folder in s3 using python 
sample: `s3://main_folder/sub_folder1/sub_folder2/`

```
# want to enter sub_folder2 - s3://main_folder/sub_folder1/sub_folder2/
import boto3

def connect_to_s3():
    s3_cli = boto3.resourse('s3')
    bucket = s3_cli.Bucket('sub_folder2')
    for b in bucket.objects.all():
        print(b.key)
```

I get this error:

> raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
>   botocore.errorfactory.NoSuchBucket: An error occurred (NoSuchBucket) when calling the ListObjects operation: The specified bucket does not exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says: `The specified bucket does not exist`

This is because the `s3_cli.Bucket('sub_folder2')` wants the name of a **Bucket**, but you have provided the name of a folder and didn't tell it the name of the bucket.

If you wish to only perform operations on a subset of a bucket, you can use a `filter` with a `prefix`:

```
import boto3

def connect_to_s3():
    s3_cli = boto3.resourse('s3')
    bucket = s3_cli.Bucket('my-bucket')
    for b in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='sub_folder1/sub_folder2/').all():
        print(b.key)
```

Comment: Can you just give me a sample how can i create sub_folder3 in sub_folder2 or some file in sub_folder2?

Comment: Folders do not existing in Amazon S3. Instead, the `Key` of an object contains the full path, eg `folder1/folder2/foo.txt`. Therefore, you can create an object in any folder, even if the folder doesn't exist! For example, in the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), you can use `aws s3 cp foo.txt s3://my-bucket/folder1/folder2/foo.txt` and it will automatically "create" the folders. But if that object is then deleted, the folders will disappear. Amazon S3 is a flat storage system, that merely simulates folders. They don't actually exist. It just looks like they do.